# Not able to select values from dropdown in select2 - #.Net

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, jquery-select2

I see this has been asked couple of times here, but none of them work for me. So i'm positing it again to see if someone faced something like this. I have a select2 inside a Model, and was able to populate it by making an ajax call to the Api. It works like a charm until here, problem is i'm not able to select any value into the 'Code'. Below is my code for the ajax and html

/*HTML*/

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-7">
            <input id="procedureSelect" name="SelectProcedure" class="form-control">
        </div>
```

/*Ajax Call */

```
$('#procedureSelect').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select Procedure',
            allowClear: true,
            quietMillis: 1000,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProcedures", "Procedure")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: term,
                        page: page
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    var more = (page * 25) < data.total;
                    return { results: data.procedureData, more: more };
                }
            },
            formatResult: function (data) {
                return '<div>' + data.procedure_code + " - " + data.short_description + '</div>';
            },

            formatSelection: function (data) {
                var result = data.procedureData;
                return result.procedure_code;
            }
        });
```

[image: Select2 inside a Model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer, by doing some more research. The Thing is select2 expects a unique Id for the data returned. So o added below one line of code to my javascript to assign the Id

```
id: function (data) { return data.procedure_code; },
```

Now it works fine.